# pandas - pivot table to square matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple dataframe in a `data.csv` file:

```
I,C,v
a,b,1
b,a,2
e,a,1
e,c,0
b,d,1
a,e,1
b,f,0
```

I would like to pivot it, and then return a square table (as a matrix). So far I've read the dataframe and build a pivot table with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
d = pd.pivot_table(df,index='I',columns='C',values='v')
d.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

correctly obtaining:

```
C  a  b  c  d  e  f
I                  
a  0  1  0  0  1  0
b  2  0  0  1  0  0
e  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Now I would like to return a square table with the missing columns indices in the rows, so that the resulting table would be:

```
C  a  b  c  d  e  f
I                  
a  0  1  0  0  1  0
b  2  0  0  1  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  1  0  0  0  0  0
f  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) can add rows and columns, and fill missing values with 0:

```
index = d.index.union(d.columns)
d = d.reindex(index=index, columns=index, fill_value=0)
```

yields

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f
a  0  1  0  0  1  0
b  2  0  0  1  0  0
c  0  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  1  0  0  0  0  0
f  0  0  0  0  0  0
```